# Caching in Automapper Resolver to increase performance

Tags: caching, automapper, resolver

As follows, I m using auto mapper to convert tasks

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Task, GanttTask>().ForMember(dst => dst.parentIdRaw, opt => opt.ResolveUsing<TaskParentIdResolver>())
```

so in TaskParentIdResolver,

```
public class TaskParentIdResolver : ValueResolver<Task, int?>
{
   protected IUow Uow { get; set; }
   public TaskParentIdResolver()
    {
        RepositoryFactories factory = new RepositoryFactories();
        IRepositoryProvider provider = new RepositoryProvider(factory);
        this.Uow = new Uow(provider);
    }
   protected override int? ResolveCore(Task source)
    {
        if (source.ParentId != null && source.ParentId != Guid.Empty)
        {
            var task = Uow.Tasks.GetById(source.ParentId.Value);
            return task.Id;
        }
        else return null;
    }
}
```

The problem i faced is,

```
var tasksList = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<Task>, IEnumerable<GanttTask>>(Uow.Tasks.GetAll().Where(con => con.IsProjectSummary == true)).ToList();
```

If i have  200 task then resolver called as 200 times and each time Uow takes time to return to resolve the parentId. Is there any way to cache this task list in resolver so that only first UOw calls the task and all the other times it returns the cache list of tasks.

Answer (score 2):

Don't put caching in AutoMapper, put it in whatever service that AutoMapper uses. If you're using an ORM, use the caching available in the ORM.